# Error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Este es el código php donde quiero generar un XML a partir de las consultas en MySQL:

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$xmlout = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
$xmlout .= "<persons>\n";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from wp_cf7dbplugin_submits");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
 $xmlout .= "\t<person>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t\t<rut>".$row['rut']."</rut>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t\t<nombre>".$row['nombre']."</nombre>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t\t<apellido>".$row['apellido']."</apellido>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t\t<correo>".$row['correo']."</correo>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t\t<telefonomovil>".$row['telefonomovil']."</telefonomovil>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t\t<carrera>".$row['carrera']."</carrera>\n";
 $xmlout .= "\t</person>\n";
}

$xmlout .= "</persons>";
echo $xmlout;
?>
```

[image: basededatos]

Cuando lo ejecuto me da el siguiente mensaje:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 115 at column 11: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

¿Que podrá ser?

Comment: porque no ocupas SimpleXMLElement de php?

Comment: Como primer paso se podrían eliminar los saltos de líneas y tabuladores (\n y \t) de la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es propiamente PHP, sino que no estás generando correctamente el XML. Revisa el código fuente en el navegador, específicamente en la línea 115, columna 11 (que es donde se muestra el error), puede que haya un caracter que está rompiendo la estructura, tal vez un mayor que o menor que.

Quizá lo soluciones usando **[htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php)** para cada columna que pueda contener estos caracteres.